# How to make a Google Drive folder private/hidden

Tags: google-drive

Okay I am bodybuilding and I take an embarassing number of selfies. I also get drunk and do stupid things with other drunk people, sometimes for a week. Photography abounds.

I don't want this stuff ever appearing on my phone or being dragged up by some AI, or even appearing as I swipe through my photos with a colleague peering into my phone while I try and find the picture of a whiteboard I took in a meeting.

Years ago, I once was chatting to my cleaner when over her shoulder I spotted that my screensaver had pulled a pic from my then Skydrive of me totally naked on the floor of my flat in 2004. :-/

Do I need to stick all this stuff in Dropbox or is there a way I can hide this stuff within my own Google Drive account?

It's a genuine problem.

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive hasn't a setting to prevent that an application that has access to account files do not access to certain files.

One solution is to have two accounts, one for "normal" files and another for "private" files. Avoid to add the second account to

- a mobile device in order to prevent that inadvertently an app has access to it.
- a backup and sync application in order to prevent that inadvertently a desktop app has access to them.

Another solution is to encrypt your the private files so they could only be opened when you un-encrypt them.

Comment: Thanks. The trouble with dual accounts is that you can't run two apps or accounts on the same android device. The encryption content gave me an idea, which is to put them in a zip. The problem then comes when I want to send an embarrassing photo of a mate on WhatsApp or, I want to send a pic to my wife who also trains, or something even more revealing (just saying :)) I can't now open the zip from the app. Grrr.

Comment: @LukePuplett : android devices allow to add more than one account but you should be careful regarding app permissions and settings.

Comment: By the way, mobile apps are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Oh(?!) Well thanks for answering, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you store photos on Google Photos, you can archive any pictures you like and they won't appear on the main screen, or in albums (unless you also put them in an album). They'll still be shareable with your mates.